# Why does my smooth mesh becomes unsmooth after I adjust the pose?

Tags: bones, pose-mode, vertex-weights, smooth, surface-deform

Recently I was rigging a character which I extract the mesh from another game as a .obj file.
When I imported it into Blender, every things was fine.

But after I rigged it with bones and assigned it with Auto weight, then problem happens when I was trying to adjust the pose and check out the weights.

The problem is, when I changed the pose, the mesh becomes unsmooth, little flat surfaces appears, like the shoulder in the image below (I rotated the shoulder bone).

What should I do to keep my mesh smooth? Is this has something to do with normals?

It seems that this problem has nothing to do with bone weights. Because whenever I deform my mesh, those flat surfaces appear (for example, when I drag some vertex in the edit mode that causes deformation).

[image: Before]

[image: After]

[image]

Comment: Consider using Rigify's animation rig (*rig*) and not the meta rig (*metarig*). The meta rig is used to adjust the bone structure to the mesh. It won't help you much with animation and facial expressions. The animation rig is created with the *Generate Rig* button. It will not work for your meta rig because you separated the teeth and mouth bones for some reason. There are also a few bones misaligned which will cause errors. I recommend watching a Rigify tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, and yes, I have been watching some tutorials about Rigify plugin. But seems Rigify is not what I need, because I am targeting UE5, so it seems that I only need deform bones for later creating control rig in UE5. I created a bone controlling eye movement in this file, but when I imported .fbx into UE5, it's not working the same way in blender. @Blunder

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your Blender mesh is separated into different parts for some reason.
You can check if a mesh is divided into separate objects by entering *Edit Mode* and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Numpad +</kbd>.

By doing this, you will see that your mesh ends and continues on another mesh.
You can solve this by entering edit mode, selecting all with  <kbd>A</kbd>, and pressing  <kbd>M</kbd> to merge by distance.

[image]

I would clear the parent first so you get the automatic weight paints.
Select the mesh, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> > *Keep Transform*.

After that, redo the parenting by selecting the mesh first, then the bones, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> for automatic weight painting.

Now the whole mesh should be affected.

Just a tip on the side:

It looks like you enabled auto-smooth shading. This is a good feature, but not the best for soft-body shadings. I'd recommend you press  <kbd>W</kbd> and just select the *Shade Smooth* option. (Not *Shade Auto Smooth*)

This feature is better for hardsurface models, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Changing to Shade Smooth mode solved my problem! And also thanks for your elaborate answer about the seperated parts. As for this mesh, I intentionally keeped the mesh parts seperated that way for later painting bone weights manually.